# SQL Selecting character string between multiple character non constant

Tags: t-sql, substring, charindex

My `SUBSTRING`/`CHARINDEX` query broke a few nights ago and I'm struggling to understand why. 
I'm trying to select the characters (Date) between "Appt. Date:" and "Appt. Time:" in comments like:

```
Status: Future Appointment  Appt. Date:12/14/18  Appt. Time:9:30am
Status: Obtaining Results  Appt. Date:10/05/18  Appt. Time:4:00
Status:   Appt. Date:8/28/2018  Appt. Time: 9:15am
```

Using this query:

```
select ltrim(
            rtrim(
                SUBSTRING([Order Comments], 
                      CHARINDEX('Appt. Date:', [Order Comments]) + LEN('Appt. Date:'), 
                      CHARINDEX('Appt. Time',[Order Comments], CHARINDEX('Appt. Date:', [Order Comments])) - 
                          (CHARINDEX('Appt. Date:', [Order Comments]) + LEN('Appt. Date:'))
                 )
            )
        ) as 'OrderApptDate'
FROM [HIRS_Tools].[dbo].[OMT_BOD]
WHERE [Order Comments] like 'status:%'
```

SQL error:

> Invalid Length Parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Should I be taking a different approach to selecting the date characters, or is there simply a problem with my current query? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: does all the data follow "Appt. Date: .... Appt. Time" format?

Comment: Yes, but not the characters previous to Appt. Date:

Comment: Did you try displaying the value of the length expression: `select [Order Comments], CHARINDEX('Appt. Time',[Order Comments], CHARINDEX('Appt. Date:', [Order Comments])) - 
                          (CHARINDEX('Appt. Date:', [Order Comments]) + LEN('Appt. Date:') as TargetLength from ...;`? Any unusual values? You ought to be able to pick it apart piece by piece until you find either the errant expression or the (Shocking!) bad data.

Comment: HABO - Thank you for this code and the good idea. I'll try using this to find the bad data. With 150 plus entry users, Shockingly bad data is sometimes the norm around here. (lol)

Comment: Well, this is a poor design for the database to begin with. The appointment time and date should be stored in a dedicated `DateTime2` column (or `Date` and `Time` columns).

Comment: Zohar Peled, I agree, but have to work within the construct of my environment. If I want to keep this job anyway. Thanks for the comment just the same.

Comment: I tried your code with the 3 example values given and it seems to execute without issue - could you perhaps provide examples which definitely cause the error?

Comment: Here is what I ran, which seems to work fine: https://rextester.com/OAD60699

Answer (score 1):

First, many thanks for the posts everyone. Even though none of them gave me the exact answer, they all gave me a piece to answer the puzzle. Especially, HABO and 3N1GM4!

Eventually I discovered the Appt Date and Appt Time fields are not always exactly the same. There are combinations of Appt. Date: & Appt. Time, Appt. Date - & Appt. Time, Appt Date & Appt. Time...All discovered from HABO's field length expression. 
So, I added a case statement adjusting for each [Appt Date/Appt Time] combo field length. This resolved everything and gave me enough leverage to have my users go clean up the remaining records and implement a better data entry work flow.

The new query looks like this:

```
select
 case 
  when CHARINDEX('Appt. Time',[Order Comments], CHARINDEX('Appt. Date:', [Order Comments])) - (CHARINDEX('Appt. Date:', [Order Comments]) + LEN('Appt. Date:')) <15
  and [Type]='Procedure' AND [Order Comments] like 'status:%' and [Order Comments] like '%Appt. Time%'
       then ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Order Comments], CHARINDEX('Appt. Date:', [Order Comments]) + LEN('Appt. Date:'), CHARINDEX('Appt. Time:',[Order Comments], CHARINDEX('Appt. Date:', [Order Comments])) - (CHARINDEX('Appt. Date:', [Order Comments]) + LEN('Appt. Date:')))))
  when CHARINDEX('Appt. Time',[Order Comments], CHARINDEX('Appt. Date:', [Order Comments])) - (CHARINDEX('Appt. Date:', [Order Comments]) + LEN('Appt. Date:')) <15
  and [Type]='Procedure' AND [Order Comments] like 'status:%' and [Order Comments] like '%Appt Time%'
       then ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Order Comments], CHARINDEX('Appt Date:', [Order Comments]) + LEN('Appt Date:'), CHARINDEX('Appt Time:',[Order Comments], CHARINDEX('Appt Date:', [Order Comments])) - (CHARINDEX('Appt Date:', [Order Comments]) + LEN('Appt Date:')))))
  when (CHARINDEX('Appt. Time',[Order Comments], CHARINDEX('Appt. Date -', [Order Comments])) - (CHARINDEX('Appt. Date -', [Order Comments]) + LEN('Appt. Date -'))) <15
  and [Type]='Procedure' AND [Order Comments] like 'status:%' and [Order Comments] like '%Appt. Date -%'
       then ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Order Comments], CHARINDEX('Appt. Date -', [Order Comments]) + LEN('Appt. Date -'), CHARINDEX('Appt. Time:',[Order Comments], CHARINDEX('Appt. Date -', [Order Comments])) - (CHARINDEX('Appt. Date -', [Order Comments]) + LEN('Appt. Date -')))))
  when (CHARINDEX('Appt. Time',[Order Comments], CHARINDEX('Appt. Date ', [Order Comments])) - (CHARINDEX('Appt. Date ', [Order Comments]) + LEN('Appt. Date '))) <15
  and [Type]='Procedure' AND [Order Comments] like 'status:%' and [Order Comments] like '%Appt. Date %'
       then ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Order Comments], CHARINDEX('Appt. Date ', [Order Comments]) + LEN('Appt. Date '), CHARINDEX('Appt. Time:',[Order Comments], CHARINDEX('Appt. Date ', [Order Comments])) - (CHARINDEX('Appt. Date ', [Order Comments]) + LEN('Appt. Date ')))))
       else [Date - Due] end as 'OrderApptDate'

FROM [HIRS_Tools].[dbo].[OMT_BOD]
WHERE ([Order Comments] like 'status:%')
```

Again, thank you for the help and I hope someone finds this useful in the future.